# Extracting and grouping using Python

Tags: python, scripting

Below is part of a log file, which is logging individual requests over some period of time. Write a python program to generate a report of the total number of steps walked  per customer. I have a log file which contains the below lines.

```
01-01-2012 01:13:36 ygyfyeic  vyeywq Customerid:1231 walked 245 steps
01-09-2013 01:18:34 gghjjhkl  fyuftf Customerid:56789 walked 678 steps
01-09-2013 01:18:34 hugigygu  hoiigy Customerid:1231  walked 456 steps
01-09-2013 01:18:34  ghguh   kjhih    Customerid:1678 walked 600 steps
```

I am able to extract Customer id and number of steps in a different lists, but I am stuck at creating a report like, number of steps taken by each customer.

Note: date keep changes, and no.of customer ids are not same.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already extracted the data into two separate lists, lets call them `ids` and `steps`.  We can print out a report by doing the following:

```
for i in range(len(ids)):
    print('Customer number %s took %s steps' % (ids[i], steps[i]))
```

You could alternatively use the [zip function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), which puts together two or more lists into a list of tuples containing the corresponding elements of each:

```
for cid, csteps in zip(ids, steps):
    print('Customer number %s took %s steps' % (cid, csteps))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas and dataframe,

From this **i am able to extract Customer id and no of steps in a different lists** i assume you have customerid and steps in 2 diff list.

import pandas as pd

```
cid = [1231,56789,1231,1678]
steps=[1,2,3,4]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'cid': cid,
    'steps':steps
})

print(df.groupby(['cid']).sum())
```

o/p

```
       steps
cid         
1231       4
1678       4
56789      2
```

ref : http://www.shanelynn.ie/summarising-aggregation-and-grouping-data-in-python-pandas/